# Windows authentication prompt box

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am getting the error-

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Configuration Error    Description: An error occurred during the
>   processing of a configuration file required to service this request.
>   Please review the specific error details below and modify your
>   configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Sections must only appear once per config file.
>   See the help topic  for exceptions.

Source Error:

```
Line 26:     <authentication mode="Windows"/>
Line 27: 
Line 28:     <authentication mode="Forms">
Line 29:       
Line 30:       <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />





<system.web>

<authorization>

  <allow users="CTS\dilip,CTS\global"/>
  <deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

<authentication mode="Windows"/>

<authentication mode="Forms">

  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />

</authentication>


<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>

<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</profile>

<roleManager enabled="false">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Comment: This looks similar to an answer I posted a little while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28681506/allowing-users-to-log-into-web-application-using-active-directory-with-c-sharp

Comment: What is the error - very poor question with out any real informations that can be used to solve anything. Start with a tutorial page that works.

Comment: Now can u get the error, i have edited the question

Comment: Do you have create a web page to get the common login form ?

Comment: No, by default its present in the asp.net web application.